# Using COM methods in console application

Tags: c++, com, console-application, ocx

i made a win32 console application that imports an ".ocx" file from geovision SDK. I found proper CLSID and interface ID of COM components in generated ".tli" and ".tlh" headers and everything works until i invoke any method(Login2 for example in my code below). Then _com_exception occurs and it gives no detailed info about what exactly happens.

Can anybody give me a hint what should i do next or where should i look for solution? It took me over a week to reach this point of using COM components in console application... I hope its possible to do it.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"

#import "C:\Windows\GeoOCX\SinglePlayer\20121003\GVSinglePlayer.ocx" \
        named_guids no_namespace no_smart_pointers 

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        CoInitialize(NULL);
        _DGVSinglePlayer* pSP = 0;
        HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_GVSinglePlayer  ,NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,DIID__DGVSinglePlayer,reinterpret_cast  <void**>(&pSP));

        _bstr_t lpIPAddress("11.11.11.11");
        long iPort=10000;
        _bstr_t lpUserID("abcde");
        _bstr_t lpPassword("password");

        if ( SUCCEEDED ( hr ) )
        {
            hr = pSP->Login2(lpIPAddress,iPort,lpUserID,lpPassword );
            if ( SUCCEEDED ( hr ) )
            {
                printf("Cool");
            }
        }else
        {
        }
        pSP->Release();
        CoUninitialize();

    } catch (_com_error& e)
    {
        char buf[80];
        sprintf(buf, "Error: %S",e.Description());
        printf("%s\n",buf);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Since e.Description() prints no info, I attatched visual info about the error.

[image: error messages]

Comment: What does `CoCreateInstance` return? Do not test using the `SUCCEEDED` macro, but rather with `S_OK == hr`. A method could return `S_FAILED` and the `SUCCEEDED` macro will evaluate to TRUE.

Comment: E_UNEXPECTED is sloppy error reporting.  The only thing accurate about it is that you didn't expect it either.  I suspect you do have to give a better IP address, port number and username+password to get somewhere.  What you used just looks like a random guess.  Contact the author of this code if you need help.

Comment: its my code and i put random data just here.when i'm debugging it im using tested data that i previously checked. what is more it throws the same error regardless of method i use

Answer (score 2):

Many ActiveX controls want to be properly hosted (meaning, the host implements `IOleClientSite` and related interfaces, and passes the pointer to the control's `IOleObject::SetClientSite`). Such controls return E_UNEXPECTED for all method calls until the OLE activation dance is performed.

In particular, ActiveX controls developed with MFC usually behave this way; the behavior is baked into MFC framework.

I suspect your control might be one of those. In this case, you wouldn't be able to use it easily in a console app. You would need a windowed application using a framework that implements ActiveX hosting (MFC, ATL, WinForms; others likely exist that I'm not familiar with).

Comment: well, thanks, that may be a good hint and maybe even the answer for my whole problem but honestly i really wanted to avoid this kind of solution. I'll try to dig some more about those "incompatible" activeXes